# How to get file upload with multiple-files working with SpringBoot + JBoss EAP 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, jboss, multipart

There's a situation that's driving me crazy, so after looking for the answer and not finding the right one, I'm here.

Well, I have a SpringBoot app deployed on a Jboss EAP 6.1. The problem is that there's a view where I need to do a multiple files upload. After the request is sent (as I can see in debug mode) there's only the last file of the view in the array.

I will post some code here so maybe you can help me.

View:

```
<form id="formCadastroSolicitacaoDadosEspecificos" method="post"
        th:action="@{/solicitacao/cadastroDadosEspecificos}"
        th:object="${solicitacao}"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
     ... some code here....
            <div class="panel-body">
                <th:block th:each="dObrigatorio, dObrigatorioStat : *{listDocumentoSolicitacao}"
                    th:if="*{listDocumentoSolicitacao != null}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="arquivo" class="control-label"
                            th:text="${dObrigatorio.tipodocumento.descricao}"></label> 
                            <input type="file" class="form-control app-modalAdicionarDocumento" 
                            name="documentos"/>
                    </div>
                </th:block>
            </div>
            <p class="text-center">
                <button id="btnCadastrarSolicitacao" type="submit"
                class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Finalizar Cadastro</button>
            </p>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
...some code here....
@RequestMapping(value="cadastroDadosEspecificos", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String cadastroDadosEspecificos(
            @RequestParam(name = "documentos") MultipartFile[] documentos,
            @RequestParam(name = "quesitos", required = false) String quesitos,
            @ModelAttribute("solicitacao") Solicitacao solicitacao,
            Model model) {
        //TODO
        //solicitacaoService.salvar(solicitacao);
        return VIEW_LISTAR_SOLICITACOES;
    }
...some code here....
```

As I said before, when debugging the app the array "MultipartFile[] documentos" has only the last file selected in the view.

I think the problem might be in the Jboss because I downloaded this code: [HelloKoding](https://hellokoding.com/uploading-multiple-files-example-with-spring-boot/) and works fine in Tomcat

Anyone have a clue about whats happening and how can I get this working?

Thank you a lot

EDIT 1:

I tested the app today with JBoss 7.1 and works perfectly. So the problem is in the JBoss 6.1 (and the company can't use another version). If anyone know whats the solution for this I appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

add multiple=multiple at the end of your input tag!
In this moment you're uploading a single file!

Comment: can you add more detail, perhaps show how to write the code with the input tags in place?